# Gradient calculation (Backward propagation ) for svm along with formula

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am able to calculate the forward propagation scores .Could any one provide me the backward propagation calculation for the values provided here .
Also Please explain how the lines in graph are drawn and how it changes when "start repeated parameter update" is clicked.
Please provide sample calculation/explanation for the default values when you load the page.

http://vision.stanford.edu/teaching/cs231n-demos/linear-classify/

[image]

Below shows the graph for computation (i am not sure its 100% correct)

[image]

formula for gradient loss calculation is is

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where's your code? Or is this not a programming problem?

Comment: this is a math problem

Comment: Okay.. in that case, the programming tag was unneeded, I've removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155088/gradient-for-hinge-loss-multiclass for multiple answers explaining the backprop derivation of the data loss (multiclass SVM loss).

The (L2) regularization's loss backprop is `2 * lambda * W`.  You add this onto dL/dW from the data loss.

Note: biases `b` are not reflected in regularization, because we don't want to penalize the y-intercept of our learned decision boundaries.  Penalizing the y-intercept would mean bias is near-zero, so each decision boundary would pass close to the origin.

---

"Start repeated parameter update" basically turns on gradient descent to update the linear classifier's weights given:

- Loss function (selection in bottom right)
- L2 regularization strength (slider in lower right)
- Step size (slider above buttons)

The colorful lines are the decision boundaries for each of the three classes.  The arrow points in the direction of positive score (`W dot x + b`).  Each row of weights `W` and biases `b` pertain to one class.  The two `W`'s control the decision boundaries' slope and the bias `b` controls the y intercept.

Gradient descent is automatically learning the `W` and `b` that minimize the total loss (data loss + regularization loss).  As learning continues, `W` and `b` are updated and so we see the decision boundary lines moving.

Eventually, learning plateaus as the solver "converges" (gets very close to minimum possible loss), and the decision boundaries stop shifting.